# Complex Analysis: Laurent Series Expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am given the following.

> > Let $f(z) = \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{z^4}$. Give a Laurent Series for $f(z)$ in terms of powers of $z$. For which values of $z$ does the Laurent series converge? Justify your answer.

Laurent Series is new to me. I am familiar with Taylor Series and it seems similar. If I am not mistaken, the Laurent series is a the series representation in terms of both positive and negative powers of $(z - z_0)$.

This is my approach thus far.

\begin{eqnarray}
f(z) & = & \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{z^4}\\
& = & \frac{1}{z^4}[e^z - e^{-z}]\\
& = & \frac{2}{z^4}\cdot\frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}\\
& = & \frac{2}{z^4}\sinh(z)\\
& = & \frac{2}{z^4}\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\\
& = & \sum_0^{\infty}\frac{2z^{2k-3}}{(2k+1)!}\\
\end{eqnarray}

I am wondering whether I approached it correct or not. Where do I continue from here? I want to say this is what I would do next, but I am not sure. With a slight change of index (z = 2k - 3), then we have the Laurent series representation

\begin{eqnarray}
f(z) & = & \sum_{n = -3}^{-\infty}\frac{2z^n}{(n + 4)!}
\end{eqnarray}

This is where I am really stuck because I am sure a negative factor is undefined.

I am sure once I figure out the Laurent series, figuring out what values of $z$ makes the series converge would involve the use of a ratio test of some sort.

Thank you for your time and Thanks in advanced for your feedback.

Comment: the Series converges everywhere except at $z=0$ so the region of convergence is $|z|>0$. Rest seems okay ... but why change index?

Comment: Looks good to me. Change of index is personal preference, so do whatever you'd like beyond the series manipulation. Although, I think you meant $n = 2k - 3$ instead of $z$, and the modified sum should go to $+\infty$